# How to get handle to base calendar without an active project

Tags: vba, calendar, handle, enterprise, ms-project

I am using project online - i want to use a macro to add public holidays to the enterprise base calendar.  From research and trials i know that the command i need is:

activeproject.basecalendar("standard").exceptions.add(

But the problem is that when you edit an enterprise base calendar, it opens in project desktop to be updated, but there is no active project, so the command doesn't work.

so:  How could I 'get' the base calendar in a macro without an active project?